# Finding all subfolders that contain two files that end with certain strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a folder, say D:\Tree, that contains only subfolders (names may contain spaces). These subfolders contain a few files - and they may contain files of the form `"D:\Tree\SubfolderName\SubfolderName_One.txt"` and `"D:\Tree\SubfolderName\SubfolderName_Two.txt"` (in other words, the subfolder may contain both of them, one, or neither). I need to find every occurence where a subfolder contains both of these files, and send their absolute paths to a text file (in a format explained in the following example). Consider these three subfolders in D:\Tree:

```
D:\Tree\Grass contains Grass_One.txt and Grass_Two.txt
D:\Tree\Leaf contains Leaf_One.txt
D:\Tree\Branch contains Branch_One.txt and Branch_Two.txt
```

Given this structure and the problem mentioned above, I'd to like to be able to write the following lines in myfile.txt:

```
D:\Tree\Grass\Grass_One.txt D:\Tree\Grass\Grass_Two.txt
D:\Tree\Branch\Branch_One.txt D:\Tree\Branch\Branch_Two.txt
```

How might this be done? Thanks in advance for any help!

Note: It is very important that "file_One.txt" comes before "file_Two.txt" in myfile.txt

Comment: One thing that I've considered doing was making a list using "dir D:\Tree\*_One.txt /b /s > somefile.txt" and another list "dir D:\Tree\*_Two.txt /b /s > somefile2.txt" using cmd, but then I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: since the question is tagged with "python" please add your code to see where the problem is.

Comment: My advice is to take a look at [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk), try something and then ask a more specific question if you get stuck. People need to know what you actually did and why it failed, not what you've considered doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution

```
def findFiles(writable, current_path, ending1, ending2):
    '''
    :param writable:    file to write output to
    :param current_path: current path of recursive traversal of sub folders
    :param postfix:     the postfix which needs to match before
    :return: None
    '''

    # check if current path is a folder or not
    try:
        flist = os.listdir(current_path)
    except NotADirectoryError:
        return


    # stores files which match given endings
    ending1_files = []
    ending2_files = []


    for dirname  in flist:
        if dirname.endswith(ending1):
            ending1_files.append(dirname)
        elif dirname.endswith(ending2):
            ending2_files.append(dirname)

        findFiles(writable, current_path+ '/' + dirname, ending1, ending2)

    # see if exactly 2 files have matching the endings
    if len(ending1_files)  == 1 and len(ending2_files) == 1:
        writable.write(current_path+ '/'+ ending1_files[0] + ' ')
        writable.write(current_path + '/'+ ending2_files[0] + '\n')


findFiles(sys.stdout, 'G:/testf', 'one.txt', 'two.txt')
```

Comment: Forgive my inexpertise, but what exactly is a postfix and how do I define it in this case? Looking at the logic it seems to be what's at the end of the files I'm looking for (so _One.txt I guess), but how do I tell this script what the two possible endings are?

Comment: I improved the solution, now it passes two endings and prints files that match them

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

folderPath = r'Your Folder Path'

for (dirPath, allDirNames, allFileNames) in os.walk(folderPath):
    for fileName in allFileNames: 
        if fileName.endswith("One.txt") or fileName.endswith("Two.txt") :
            print (os.path.join(dirPath, fileName)) 
            # Or do your task as writing in file as per your need
```

Hope this helps....